# Apache map a port to a public directory

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I have this directory in a vm

```
/www/app1
```

and I want to be able to go to `http://192.168.1.1:7778` and go to that directory

how do I configure that using CentOS 7 minimal install? I just went through LAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`root@machine1 httpd]# systemctl status httpd.service
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-12-02 14:26:52 WET; 55s ago
  Process: 3257 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3256 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3256 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)`

`Dec 02 14:26:52 develop.wsclabs.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 02 14:26:52 machine1.domain.com httpd[3256]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/vh-test.conf:
Dec 02 14:26:52 machine1.domain.com httpd[3256]: Require not allowed here
Dec 02 14:26:52 machine1.domain.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 02 14:26:52 machine1.domain.com kill[3257]: kill: cannot find process ""
Dec 02 14:26:52 machine1.domain.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 02 14:26:52 machine1.domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 02 14:26:52 machine1.domain.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.`

So I edited the vh-test.conf and commented the require line
I'm getting this error now
`httpd[3364]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80`

Trying to figure this one out

Comment: Ok I solved this one already. I had included
`Listen 80`

On top of vh-test.conf, removing it allowed httpd to start with no problems. Now I need to know how to allow the VM to accept connections to the custom ports.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have this line in your apache configuration file:

```
listen: 80
```

After this line add this:

```
listen:7778
```

Then down below the virtualhosts definitions, add this

```
<VirtualHost *:7778>
  ServerAdmin someone@somehost
  DocumentRoot /www/app1
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  Require all granted
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart apache server

Note: this is a minimal configurarion set, be advised that you have to watch over several security directives in your virtualhosts

Note 2: apache configuration file may be a single file (i.e: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`), or may be an array of files frecuently located at `{apache_path}/sites-enabled/`

Comment: Hi Eduardo thanks for your reply. I am going to test and will come back.